# HTML input text font-family not being applied on iPad

Tags: android, html, ipad, input, font-family

I have simple web page (https://cfmeng.azurewebsites.net/cfusion/test.cfm), in the web page, I have some text Input and each text input will show different fonts.

This works perfectly on PC. However, on iPad and Android (Sumsung), all input text shows the same font regardless what font-family setup for the input.

My goal is to use a font other than default to show the input text.

I tried

```
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 20px;"><br>

<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" style="font-family: 'Brush Script MT'; font-size: 20px;"><br>

<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif,'Arial Black'; font-size: 20px;"><br>
```

The above three shows differently on PC as you type, but exactly the same on mobile device (iPad/Android)

Thank you!

George

Answer (score 0):

Looks like both device are missing the font-family, so it just use default fonts.

I used embedded font, it worked right away on mobile devices.

The working url is at https://cfmeng.azurewebsites.net/cfusion/test2.cfm

Use Android or iPad to run this url, the result shows up correctly.